# Why does this program print the message more than once?

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, control-flow

I'm new to programming and made a simple program to determine if a user inputted number was even or odd. I also made a function that checks if the inputted number is an integer rather than a float.

The program mostly executes correctly if a user types a number, but the message telling whether the number is odd or even prints multiple times if the user inputs multiple floats first. Why does that happen?

```
def check_int(x,y):
    if x != int(x):
        print "The number is not an integer"
        y()
    else:
        print "The number is an integer"

def even_odd():
    given_number = input("Please type an integer: ")
    check_int(given_number, even_odd)
    if (given_number % 2) != 0:
        print "The number is odd"
    elif (given_number % 2) == 0:
        print "The number is even"

even_odd()
```

Comment: What's `n % 2` for some float n? To help debug your program, try `print '{} is the number'.format(x)` in different spots.

Comment: use str.isdigit

Comment: Change `input` to `raw_input` when you're using Python 2. `input` is the correct function when using Python 3.

Comment: `check_int` doesn’t return in the `x != int(x)` case until `y()` does, so the `print "The number is odd"` (which seems incorrect for non-integers, but it’s true that `1.5 % 2 != 0`) waits for the next call of `even_odd` to exit.

Comment: why do you use `y()` inside `check_int()` ? you create recursion.

Comment: that's because each call to even_odd you'll get the print out ("The number is odd" or "The number is even") and for a float number even_odd would be called more than once.

Comment: When `check_int(x,y)` calls `y()`, which is `odd_even()` in your example, `odd_even()` then calls `check_int()`—circular logic—so that's why the message appears twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`even_odd` is called from within `check_int` again (under the name `y`). That's why you see its output multiple times.

I suppose you think this is required in order to continue with `even_odd` after `check_int` is finished. This is not necessary. When a function is finished, the program automatically continues from where the function was called.

Simply remove the `y` parameter from `check_int`, remove the line `y()` and change `check_int(given_number, even_odd)` to `check_int(given_number)`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you've used an arcane version of recursion to loop through your program.  When you receive a float, you call **check_int**, print the message, and then *recur to the input function*.  This leaves a hanging return to your first call on the stack.  When you finally get an integer, you leave **check_int** normally, but then return to **even_odd**, which is still waiting to process the parity of the floats.  That's what produces the extra lines of output.

When you reject something as a non-integer, you need to loop back to the input, or otherwise avoid checking the parity later.

```
def check_int(x,y):
    return x != int(x)

def even_odd():
    given_number = input("Please type an integer: ")
    if check_int(given_number, even_odd):
        print "The number is not an integer"
    else:
        print "The number is an integer"
        # Check parity
        if (given_number % 2) != 0:
            print "The number is odd"
        elif (given_number % 2) == 0:
            print "The number is even"

even_odd()
```

If you want to loop until you get an integer, write that as a separate, outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of issues with your code.

First of all, you don't need an elif. If `given_number % 2 !=0` is false then the opposite condition will always be True. So the opposite of `!= 0` is `0`.

Also, don't pass a function as a callback. The way you wrote it could possibly crash your program. I suggest you read more about [loops](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm).

cheers!